# Unknown device connected to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I physically removed the power cables from all networked devices in my home, save for my desktop. Still, in my router's DHCP table and in NirSoft's Wireless Network Watcher, I see a device with MAC address EC-0E-C4-B0-61-D5 and company name Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd. I know that company makes a TON of different devices, but I've turned off every other device in my home and it  still shows connected.

<s>In my router's DHCP table the Client Name read "kindle-xxxxxxx" (x's are in place of what seemed like a random string of alphanums), but now that I rebooted my router, it says "Unknown." I don't have a Kindle in my home. The closest thing to it is a FireTV box, and I unplugged the power cord from that.</s>

Any insight into what this device could be? I find it hard to believe its an unauthorized device because my wifi password is very strong and I use WPA2. So unless Mr. Robot is my neighbor, I don't think I've been compromised...

**EDIT:** Just FYI- After rebooting my router, this device obtains a DHCP lease approx 8 mins after my wired desktop does.

**EDIT 2:** I just blocked out the above paragraph because it was inaccurate. The "kindle-xxxxxx" device WAS my FireTV (my apologies). But the unknown Hon Hai device still remains, so issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Is this not your desktop's MAC address? Have you looked at wired devices? Note that DHCP server lease tables are not "live". If you unplugged the FireTV after it got a DHCP lease, it'll still show in the server's table until the lease expires, which may be hours or days later.

Comment: My Router/NirSoft shows 3 devices- the router, my desktop, and then the unknown one. 

I understand about the lease, but NirSoft shows this device as active, not inactive.

Comment: Change the passphrase and see who complains? Make sure to turn off WPS-PIN just in case.

Comment: run nmap against your subnet to learn more about what this device is and what it's running

Comment: @grawity - WPS is off, and if I change the passphrase I'll have to update all my devices. I should be able to figure this out with forensic tools.

Comment: @glallen - Good idea, I'll try it.